# Does Yasuo wind wall block one direction or both?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yasuo's wind wall reads "Creates a moving wall that blocks enemy projectiles."
I noticed the other day watching a game, that a Yasuo player threw up a wind wall but threw it on the wrong side of themselves (the enemy was the other direction).  They then ran to the other side of the wall, making me wonder if it blocks both ways or just one way (and they were just panic running).

It seems to be curved very slightly on the ends, but that could just be a graphics choice.

The guide video only shows Ashe shooting from a single side.

Comment: It should behave the same way despite the facing direction, much the same as Azir's ultimate. I will test this when I get home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yasuo's Windwall does block every projectile in both directions: watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZtYrb8N404) to see it block form both sides, skip to 1 min 46 secs to see it block from the back.

Answer (score 2):

Yasuo's windwall blocks in the same way from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

As an adc main, I can attest that Wind Wall blocks projectiles from both directions.  I've had plenty of duels with Yasuo's where we keep running from one side of the wall to the other.  Regardless of which side the wall was originally set up, it will block any projectile that attempts to pass through it from either side.

FWIW, Braum's E shield works the same way (it won't help Braum any if he is on the wrong side of it, but it will prevent projectiles from passing through and damaging teammates).  I'm not sure if Braum still benefits from the damage reduction if the shield is facing the wrong direction, but I suspect he does not.

Comment: It's not that Braums shield also works both ways, it's just if his shield faces the wrong way his body takes the shot obviously, so he still blocks it either way just no bonus damage reduction from behind the shield.